# Get total permissions from users & roles belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 models:

- User
- Role
- Permission

Note:

- a user can have direct permissions
- a role can have permissions
- a user can have roles

I'm trying to get the total permissions a user has, either through their direct permissions or through their roles permissions. So I need to combine both into 1 collection and count the total.

I've set up the belongsToMany relationships for `User` and `Role`:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission');
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out via [flatMap](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-flatmap).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `hasManyThrough` relation

Here is the link to the documentation: [Eloquent Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

so you would do something like this:

```
public function permissions()
{   
    $directPermissions = $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission'); 
    $rolePermissions = $this->hasManyThrough('App\Permissions', 'App\Role');
    return $directPermissions->merge($rolePermissions);
}
```

Comment: Nah I figured it out: `$user->permissions->merge($user->roles->flatMap(function ($role) {
            return $role->permissions;
        }));`

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but it will help
open your `user model`

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

public function hasRole(...$roles)
    {

        foreach($roles as $role)
        {
            if($this->roles->contains('name',$role))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

   public function hasPermission($permission)
    {
        return $this->hasPermissionThroughRole($permission) || (bool) $this->permissions->where('name',$permission->name)->count();
    }

    public function hasPermissionThroughRole($permission)
    {
        foreach($permission->roles as $role)
        {
            if($this->roles->contains($role))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then open your `Role Model` and add these

```
public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class);
    }

public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

and open your `permission model`

```
public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

and finaly to boot all the permission to roles and user 
run the command `php artisan make:provider PermissionServiceProvider`

open you service provider created newely and

add

```
use App\Permission;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
```

add the code under the `boot`  method

```
Permission::get()->map(function ($permission) 
            {
                Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) 
                {
                    return $user->hasPermission($permission);
                });
            });
```

hope it helps if you find any difficulties please comment below